# Missing Page in WordDoc

Tags: c#

I am adding images regarding  mount of "images" taken into my word as so called InlineShapes. But I have the issue that **8 images are created but only 7** are "uploaded" in the word file why so ever.

```
 int pagecount = document.PageCount;
 //With the int pagecount we can create as may screenshots as there are pages in the document
 for (int index = 1; index < pagecount; index++)
 {
     application.Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture(outputFileName + index + ".jpg");
 }
```

And yes my page count is also 8.

```
foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.InlineShape inline in doc.InlineShapes)
{

    //Special sacling is done  or landscape docs as  well as portrait doumcnets
    if (inline.Height < inline.Width)
    {
        doc.PageSetup.Orientation = WdOrientation.wdOrientLandscape;
        inline.ScaleWidth = 90;
        inline.ScaleHeight = 90;
    }
}
```

Here is the scaling done for each image when inserted into the word file and this loop "actives" it self only seven time but why ?

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `pageCount` is 8 but you are iterating from `index` 1 until it is greater than or equals to `pageCount`.

To fix this either start from `index = 0` **or** until `index <= pagecount` whichever makes sense from a logical point of view. So either:

```
for (int index = 0; index < pagecount; index++)
```

Or

```
for (int index = 1; index <= pagecount; index++)
```